# Want to use Enum file name dynamically to fetch constants

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, bdd

I have a config file with key value pair as
`language = "IN"`
and i have multiple page object enum files with name as
 `PageObject_US,PageObject_UK,PageObject_IN`

every page object enum file has constants that can be accessed using for example
`PageObjects_US.String.lable`

but what i want to achieve is a way to create something like below

1. take the parameter from config file store it in a string
   like String language = "IN"
2. Then concatenate using "PageObjects_" + language to get (PageObjects_IN)
3. so that the returned value can be used to fetch the constants from PageObjects_IN.String.label.

following is the code block:

```
if(!ENV.equalsIgnoreCase("development") && VALIDATION.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {        
            Elements.ByTitle(webDriver,PageObjects_IN.GREAT.label);
            Elements.ByID(webDriver,  PageObjects_IN.COUNTER.label);
}
```

In the above i want to use enum file PageObjects_IN at run time as i have many enum files

below is the enum

```
public enum PageObjects_IN {
    // Text
    GREAT("great"), 
    COUNTER("counter");


    public final String lable;

    PageObjects_IN(final String lable) {
        this.lable = lable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your current code?

Comment: Can you please also show the example of how your enum is defined?

Comment: @AlexeyR.  Done i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible (using reflection) but strongly not recommended as it eliminates the efficiency of Java language constructs.

**Not recommended way**

Say you have a package `click.webelement.cucumber.po` where you store

```java
public enum PO_EN {
    GREAT("great_en"),
    COUNTER("counter_en");

    public final String label;

    PO_EN(String label){
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

and

```java
public enum PO_IN {
    GREAT("great_in"),
    COUNTER("counter_in");

    public final String label;

    PO_IN(String label){
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Then to take a value you can do something like this:

```java
String lang = "EN";
// Take class
Class clazz = Class.forName("click.webelement.cucumber.po.PO_" + lang);
// Find an object that represent enum constant
Object val = Arrays
        .stream(clazz.getEnumConstants()).filter(o -> "GREAT".equals(o.toString()))
        .findAny()
        .get();
// Take field value for that object
Field f = clazz.getField("label");
System.out.println(f.get(val));
```

This is error-prone approach and you would not have benefit from compile phase.

**Recommended approach - 1**

Instead of having `enum` use classes.

```
public abstract class PO {

    public abstract String great();
    public abstract String counter();

}
```

and

```
public class PO_EN extends PO{
    @Override
    public String great() {
        return "great_en";
    }

    @Override
    public String counter() {
        return "counter_en";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class PO_IN extends PO{
    @Override
    public String great() {
        return "great_in";
    }

    @Override
    public String counter() {
        return "counter_in";
    }
}
```

so your test would be much simpler

```
String lang = "EN";
Class clazz = Class.forName("click.webelement.cucumber.po.PO_" + lang);
PO val = (PO) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
System.out.println(val.great());
```

**Recommended approach - 2**

You can utilize PageFactory harness for your page objects and use [this lib](https://github.com/webelement-click/parameterized-findby) to parametrize your locators, like (if you use test ng):

```
@DataProvider(name = "languages")
Object[][] dataProvider(){
    return new Object[][]{
            {"en", "great_en", "counter_en"},
            {"in", "great_in", "counter_in"}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "languages")
public void testPage(String language, String great, String counter){
    DefaultParameterProvider
            .properties
            .set(Map.of("p.great", great, "p.counter", counter));
    MyPage myPage = new MyPage(driver);
    ...
}
```

Where your page would be like this:

```
public class MyPage extends PageObjectParameterized {

    @FindByParameterized(xpath = "//button[@name='{wec:p.great}']")
    WebElement great;

    @FindByParameterized(xpath = "//label[text()='{wec:p.counter}']")
    WebElement counter;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input")
    WebElement input;
    
    public MyPage(SearchContext searchContext) {
        super(searchContext);
    }
}
```